# Are the following union the same as the intersection?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I solved this problem, however, then given solution was different then mine in the following way: For a set $D$ defined as $D:= \{x \in E: f(x) < 0\}$, I wrote that I could define the following set
$D_k := \{x \in E: f(x) < \frac{1}{k}\}$, hence, the following holds:

$$\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}D_k = D.$$

Is this not the case? I think, if anything, there might be a problem at $f(x)=0$?

Comment: What is $E$...?

Comment: Your intersection still contains values of $x$ where $f(x)=0$.

Comment: "Is this not the case?"  No.... it is not....  But you *can* conclude $\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty D_k = F:=\{x \in E: f(x)\le 0\} = D \cup \{x\in E: f(x) = 0\}$.

Comment: The title mentions a union, but the body of the question doesn't. Please edit for consistency.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x)=0$ then $x \in\bigcap D_k$ but $x \notin D$.

$\bigcap D_k$ is $\{x \in E: f(x) \leq 0\}$.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks!